# Multivariable linear equation with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

How can I solve this system of equations of variables x, y and z:
$$
xy -2 \sqrt y + 3yz = 8 \\
2xy -3 \sqrt y + 2yz = 7\\
-xy + \sqrt y + 2yz = 4
$$

I'm used to solve problems with singular variables ( like 2x +3y-5z= k), and I saw this problem on an exam I want to aply. Thanks for giving me at least one idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=xy$, $v=\sqrt y$, and $w=yz$. Solve for $u,\ v$, and $w$. Then, solve for your original variables, as you'll have:
$$\begin{align}
xy&=u\\
\sqrt y&=v\\
yz&=w
\end{align}
$$
and you'll know the values of the three variables on the right. From there, solve for $y$ first. and use substitution to solve the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Can you solve the following linear system linear system in $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$?
\begin{align*}
a_1-2a_2+3a_3 &= 8 \\
2a_1 - 3a_2 + 2a_3 &= 7 \\
-a_1 + a_2 + 2a_3 &= 4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the "linear" system leads to a solution of the form

$$\begin{cases}xy&=a,\\\sqrt y&=b,\\yz&=c.\end{cases}$$

Now taking the logarithm and using uppercase to denote it, this is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}X+Y&=A,\\\dfrac12Y&=B,\\Y+Z&=C,\end{cases}$$
another linear system.

Comment: +1 for the logarithm idea, even though it might be overkill.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX: Overkill ? In the end the solution is a product of powers (possibly noninteger), which are computed... by logarithms.

Comment: $\sqrt y=v\implies y=v^2$. This is a linear system, so $u,\ v, \text{and }w$ are all rational. This means $y$ is rational because the square of a rational number is rational. Finally, this means $x$ and $z$ are rational because the product of rational numbers is a rational number. You don't need logarithms in this case, but I could see this being necessary in more complicated situations.